# Ajax получение checked

Tags: ajax

Value я получаю так

```
var asc = $("#auth_site_check").val();
```

А как получить checked

**UPD**

```
function auth(){
var email = $("#auth_site_mail").val();
var pass = $("#auth_site_pass").val();
var result = document.getElementById('result');
if(email == ""  || pass == ""){
result.innerHTML = '<div class="ininar">'+langtext+'</div>';
}else{
var auth = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;
if(!email.match(auth)){
result.innerHTML = '<div class="ininar">'+mailno+'</div>';
}
else{
$.ajax({
url: "script/auth.php",
type: "POST",
data:{email: email,pass: pass}, 
success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
result.innerHTML = '<div class="ininar">'+data+'</div>';
}
});
}
}
```

Comment: @NetSperes, И где вам надо проверять checkbox? Догадаться с трёх попыток?

P.S. Проверять на пустоту лучше оператором **===** и название переменной (**auth**), совпадающее с именем функции - "это круто".

Comment: Я просто не давно дружу с js

Comment: @NetSperes, Подружитесь, если лень не возьмет верх. А вышеуказанный вариант подошел?

Comment: смешалось всё...

интересно в какой ад попадают те кто пишет if () {} else {if (){} else}}

Comment: deonis, нет

Answer (score 2):

Т.е. вам надо получить состояние checkbox? Тогда, метод [.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) вам в помощь.
Смотрим [на примере](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/jd8JM/).

**UPD** Судя по комментариям, читать документацию вам облом...

```
$('selector').click(function(){
    if($(this).prop('checked')){
        $.ajax({
            url: '/path_to_handler/',
            method: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {asc: $(this).val()},
            success: function(response){
                alert('Oh, my God! It\'s time to read the manual!');
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Нет просто я не понимаю как прикрутить ваше к моему

Comment: @NetSperes, я "ваше" не видел, поэтому и совет дать не могу. Показывайте относящийся к делу код, а я пока за отвёрткой схожу. Думаю, что прикрутим :)

Answer (score 1):

например

```
$("#auth_site_check").is(':checked');
```

либо

```
$("#auth_site_check:checked");
```

Comment: Ну, получается так var asc = $("#auth_site_check:checked"); 
но не отправляются data:{asc: asc},

Comment: а ну вас тогда is(':checked'), либо

    var asc=$('#auth_site_check:checked').length>0;

Comment: при $("#auth_site_check").is(':checked'); пишет false
и 
при var asc=$('#auth_site_check:checked').length>0;
false

Comment: это что-то у вас. http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/fCPPU/ (специально без this сделал, чтобы понятно было)

Comment: может у вас `id="auth_site_check"` не один на странице ?